# pre_get_posts all posts and custom post type with certain tag

Tags: pre-get-posts

I would like to display all the posts I have and custom post type pages if they have a certain tag on my home page. This is my code, but I can't get it to work:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_posts_plus_cpt_with_certain_tag' );

function get_posts_plus_cpt_with_certain_tag( $query ) {
   if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
      if ( $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'cpt' ) {     
         $taxquery = array(
            array(            
               'taxonomy' => 'cpt-tag',
               'field' => 'id',
               'terms' => 1
               )
            );      
            $query->set('tax_query', $taxquery);        
         }  
      $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'cpt' ) );               
      return $query;
   }
}
```

I'm stuck, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: updated the code, thanks to Pieter Goosen

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_posts_plus_cpt_with_certain_tag' );

function get_posts_plus_cpt_with_certain_tag( $query ) {
   if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
      if ( 1 == 1 ) {   
         $taxquery = array(
            array(            
               'taxonomy' => 'cpt_tag',
               'field' => 'term_id',
               'terms' => 27
               )
            );      
            $query->set('tax_query', $taxquery);        
         }  
      $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'cpt' ) );
   }
}
```

Comment: My problem is not fully solved yet, but I accepted your answer anyway, because it was truly helpful, thanks again. :) I commented below your answer, I'm just not very quick at typing, sorry for that!

Comment: My edit should solve your issue completely. You just needed to remove `post` from the post type array :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here

- `is_home()` should be a method of `$query`, so it should become `$query->is_home()`
- The value to the `field` parameter should be `term_id`, not `id`. `id` works, so will any crap passed as value because if you look at the source codes, the source only checks for `slug` and `name`, it does not specifically check for `term_id`. So any value will work as default. This is **wrong**. The **correct** and **only** value for term ids is `term_id`
- `pre_get_posts` is an action, not a filter
- Actions do not return, so remove `return $query`
- `1` cannot be your term id. `1` is the (*reserved*) term id of the default category term `uncategorized`. This is why your query fails to get posts. `uncategorized` is a term to the build in taxonomy `category`, not the custom taxonomy `cpt-tag`
- Your custom taxonomy cannot be `cpt-tag`. Taxonomy names should always be lowercase letters (*caveat - seems numbers are allowed as well if not the first digit*) with multiple words separated by an **underscore only**. Hyphens should be avoided as it creates issues with template names etc
- Your conditional check `if ( $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'cpt' ) {}` is also probably never returning true due to being the home page. The default `post_type` on the homepage is `post`, always if not modified by some kind of filter like `pre_get_posts`. I would just remove this.

### EDIT

From your edit, and comment, you need to remove `post` from the `post_type` array if you don't need the deafult post type posts to display. You also do not need the `1 == 1` check.

Your final code should be:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_posts_plus_cpt_with_certain_tag' );

function get_posts_plus_cpt_with_certain_tag( $query ) {
   if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

         $taxquery = array(
            array(            
               'taxonomy' => 'cpt_tag',
               'field' => 'term_id',
               'terms' => 27
               )
            );      
            $query->set('tax_query', $taxquery);        
         }  
      $query->set( 'post_type', 'cpt' );

}
```

Comment: Wow, so many mistakes, thanks for pointing them out! I really appreciate your detailed explanation, I updated the code and changed the second if statement to `1 == 1`. So the `$query->set('tax_query', $taxquery);` is working now, but now of course it applies not only to `cpt` post type, but posts too. Is there a way I can apply it only to `cpt` post type?

Comment: Please see my update. It should work as expected now :-)

Comment: Oh, it's working, but I would like to display all the `posts` too (unfiltered), _and_ the `cpt` post type pages (filtered by the `tax_query`).

Sorry for not being clear enough! :)

Comment: I have answered this question in the context it was written. What you need to do now is much more complex than what is given in  my answer. As this issue of this particular question is addressed, you should start a new question with this new requirements. And be very sure to include all info as questions are answered within the context in the question :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks! :) I started a new question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/187406/pre-get-posts-all-posts-and-custom-post-type-with-certain-tag

(I think the if's closing curly brace should be after `$query->set( 'post_type', 'cpt' );`, not before it. :))