# pre_get_posts: using tax_query only for certain post type

Tags: pre-get-posts, tax-query

I have default post type posts (post type: `post`) and custom post type posts (post type: `cpt`). The latter has a taxonomy (`cpt_tag`).

I would like to display on my front page all the default post type posts (unfiltered), *and* some of the `cpt` post type posts, only if they have a certain `cpt_tag`.

The code is:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_posts_plus_cpt_with_certain_tag' );

function get_posts_plus_cpt_with_certain_tag( $query ) {
   if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $taxquery = array(
            array(            
               'taxonomy' => 'cpt_tag',
               'field' => 'term_id',
               'terms' => 27
               )
            );      
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );                 
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'cpt' ) );
    }
}
```

The problem is `$query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );` is applied not only to `cpt` posts but `post` posts too. How could I use `tax_query` only for filtering `cpt` posts and leave `post` posts unfiltered?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

(This is a clarified version of [my previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/187406/pre-get-posts-all-posts-and-custom-post-type-with-certain-tag).)

Comment: You will need to do two queries, one for `post` and one for `cpt`, and then merge them for your loop.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic, I'm not sure how can I achieve this, but thanks for the tip, I will looking into it!

Comment: @TheDeadMedic you don't need two separate queries here. I think we all overthought a very easy solution here. `cpt_tag` is only assigned to `cpt` post type, so this makes the solution easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can understand, `cpt_tag` is only assigned to the custom post type `cpt`. This makes things much easier and less complicated. You do not need two queries and you don't need to merge anything

Here is the plan:

- We need to know which terms you need to show on the homepage from the `cpt` post type
- Using `get_terms()` and the `exclude` parameter, we will exclude the terms we need to show posts from from the `cpt` post type. The returned array from `get_terms()` will hold all the terms we don't want to show. We are also going to set the `fields` parameter to `ids` so that we get an array of term ids
- This array will be passed to the `tax_query` in `pre_get_posts`. As this is terms we need to exclude, we will set the `operator` parameter to `NOT IN` to exclude posts with these terms

You need only minor adjustments to your code to make this work

Here is an example

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_posts_plus_cpt_with_certain_tag' );

function get_posts_plus_cpt_with_certain_tag( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        /*
        * Change 110 to the term id you need to display posts from from cpt post type
        */
        $terms = get_terms( 'cpt_tag', array( 'exclude' => 110, 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
        if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            $taxquery = array(
                array(            
                    'taxonomy'  => 'cpt_tag',
                    'field'     => 'term_id',
                    'terms'     => $terms,
                    'operator'  => 'NOT IN'
                )
            );      
            $query->set('tax_query', $taxquery); 
        }   
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'cpt' ) );

    }
}
```

### EDIT 1

I did not include safety, you **should** first check if you get any results from `get_terms` before using it. I have included that in my code now

### EDIT 2

The above solution works, but there is a small glitch as pointed out in comments

> ...if I have `cpt` post type posts that have no `cpt_tag`s at all, the `tax_query` doesn't filter them out, it only filters out `cpt` post type posts with at least one `cpt_tag`...

The problem arises in the fact that custom post type posts by default doesn't have a default term assigned to it when no term is assigned to them in the same way as normal post type `post` have the term `uncategorized` assigned to them by default when no term is assigned to it

Because there is no relation to any term if no term is assigned to them, custom post type posts does not appear in the `wp_term_relationships` table, so they don't appear in a normal `tax_query`

To work around this issue, we need to slightly alter our original workflow. Here is how we are going to tackle this issue

- Get all the terms assigned to the `post` post type. By default, all posts from the `post` post type will have at least one term assigned to it unless this behavior is altered by some other drastic code. So we are 99.999% safe here.
- We are going to use the same strategy as previous but with a slight modification. We will still use `get_terms()` with the `fields` parameter set to `ids`, but here we will get all the terms. I will assume that you are using the default build-in taxonomy `category` for the `post` post type.
- We can simply just pass the term ids we need to **include** for the `cpt_tag` to our `tax_query`, nothing special here
- Remember to set the `relation` parameter to `OR` as we need posts with all terms in `category` taxonomy **or** all posts that has the specific term from the `cpt_tag` taxonomy. Omitting the `relation` parameter will default to `AND` which will fail your query as it will look for posts that have terms in `category` taxonomy **and** `cpt_tag` taxonomy

So lets put that in code:

(*I will again use term id `110` for the term for `cpt_tag`, just change accordingly*)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_posts_plus_cpt_with_certain_tag' );

function get_posts_plus_cpt_with_certain_tag( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        /*
        * Change 110 to the term id you need to display posts from from cpt post type
        */
        $terms = get_terms( 'category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
        if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            $taxquery = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array( // Includes all terms (categories) for post post type          
                    'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                    'field'     => 'term_id',
                    'terms'     => $terms,
                ),
                array( // Include the terms you need to display from cpt_tag           
                    'taxonomy'  => 'cpt_tag',
                    'field'     => 'term_id',
                    'terms'     => array( 110 ),
                ),

            );      
            $query->set('tax_query', $taxquery); 
        }   
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'cpt' ) );

    }
}
```

Comment: Any feedback on this. Please rechech my code, I had a bug

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I really like this approach, but the problem is, if I have `cpt` post type posts that have no `cpt_tag`s at all, the `tax_query` doesn't filter them out, it only filters out `cpt` post type posts with at least one `cpt_tag` (if it is not `110`). Is it possible to apply the `tax_query` to `cpt` post type posts with 0 `cpt_tag` too, without the mysterious query merging? :)

Comment: But I accept your answer anyway, because with your help at least I can do a workaround by adding some tag to each `cpt` post type posts. (Yeah, I'm not proud of it...)

Comment: Please see my **EDIT 2**. I have made a slight change to the code. This should work now without having the need to assign terms to the custom post type posts without terms :-). If you have tested it, let me know. Curious to see how it works :-)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, the code works beautifully! (There was a missing comma after the first `array` in `$taxquery`.) I love this solution, it seems pretty smart. :) Thanks again, I truly appreciate your help and detailed explanations!

Comment: My pleasure. I appreciate your feedback on this. It is always nice to tackle such unique problems. Enjoy, and thanks once again. :-)